# How to show animated gif in tree views?

Tags: c#, treeview

I need to use a blinking icon as an image for a specific item in a tree view. For this, i tried to add an animated gif file including two frames, one including the image and one an empty frame. I could add the image to the image list in designer. But it doesn't blink. I tried to figure out what's the problem, but i couldn't.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Default Windows Form does not support any animation, that's why gif file look like static image, when we use it in windows forms. If you are using windows form, then use timer control to redraw the treeview. Or use integrated wpf content in windows form(my choice)

Comment: using timer control causes the whole tree view to be refreshed for just an icon. is it avoidable?
please describe how to implement the other way.
thx

Comment: is it essentially possible for a tree view to be refreshed not wholly, just a node, a node icon or just a specific part of it? i need to avoid flickering.